# How to calculation 'Next Birthday' in a Podio field

Tags: podio

I want to be able to calculate the 'Next Birthday' date from a 'Date of Birth' field in Podio.

I cannot seem to get the calculation that makes this work.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below calculation

```
var dob = @DOB;
var nextDOB = moment(new Date(new Date(dob).setFullYear(new 
Date().getFullYear() + 1))).format('DD/MM/YYYY');;
nextDOB+"";
```

Here, we are using the JS to get the next year date corresponding to the DOB field and parse it using moment js

Comment: I have tried this but Podio won't let me save the template and throws out an error 'The type of result changed from number to text'.

Comment: @ManniSidhu Yes, you need to delete the old calculation field and a create a new one with the above script. Podio calculation field doesn't support updating script if the type of the result changes.

Comment: @NivinVJoseph Thanks, I have managed to get this to work to a certain extent. The field is now populated but the year is incorrect for some of the items as there are some birthdays that have not gone past this year butt he 'Next Birthday' field shows 2020 instead of 2019.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that this field will only calculate when the @DOB field is changed, so this will only work for the first 'next' birthday that comes up. I'd recommend using the API to set an actual date field instead of trying to use calculation fields for this.

Comment: How would this be done as I have tried to create a flow using Globiflow but can't get the flow to update just the 'Year' of the 'Next Birthday'

Comment: I think you should be able to get a flow in globiflow to do it by adding 365 days. You'll eventually get off with leap years, so I would recommend using the API and one of the SDKs for interacting with the API in a programming language of your choice.